# Making an api call inside a function causing the browser to freeze in react (typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a typescript file and having some issues ( I believe re-rendering) inside the `cellsrenderer` function as shown below:

```
cellsrenderer: (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties): string => {

         axios
            .get("api/personnels/"+value) 
               .then(response => {
                  this.setState({
                    createdByName: response.data.displayedValues 
                 }, ()=> {
               console.log('Inside axios response after setting the state to the name of the project creater')
                 })
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));


                return this.state.createdByName;

                }
```

When my code runs, I keep seeing the `console.log('Inside axios response after setting the state to the name of the project creater')` in console for many times even though I have only 30 records to display in total. The browser freezes at some point and I have to close it forcefully. It's happening only because of an API call that I am making inside `cellsrenderer` function shown above. If I just do the following, everything works fine:

```
cellsrenderer: (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties): string => {
    
            return value;
    
}
```

What issue is with the API call inside `cellsrenderer` function which is causing the browser to freeze?

In chrome I am seeing the following:

[image]

And then it throws in the browser `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` related error:

```
GET https://myserver.com/api/personnels/12345 net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:160
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:11
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:51
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:61
wrap @ bind.js:9
cellsrenderer @ Projects.tsx:261
_rendercell @ jqxgrid.js:8
_rendervisualcell @ jqxgrid.js:8
_rendervisualrows @ jqxgrid.js:8
l @ jqxgrid.js:8
_renderrows @ jqxgrid.js:8
rendergridcontent @ jqxgrid.js:8
_render @ jqxgrid.js:8
dataview.update @ jqxgrid.js:8
q @ jqxgrid.js:8
l @ jqxgrid.js:8
callDownloadComplete @ jqxdata.js:8
success @ jqxdata.js:8
bw @ jqxcore.js:8
fireWith @ jqxcore.js:8
S @ jqxdata.js:8
H @ jqxdata.js:8
Projects.tsx:269 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:69:14)
```

**Here is my complete code:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {FormikApp} from './forms/AddProjectForm'
import JqxGrid, {IGridProps, jqx} from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxgrid';
import JqxButton from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxbuttons'
import {RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router-dom'
import 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css'
import 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.material.css'
import 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.arctic.css'
import {Dialog} from "primereact/dialog";
import {Button} from "primereact/button";
import {properties} from "../properties";
import {Card} from "primereact/card";
import axios from "axios";
import {Messages} from "primereact/messages";
import _ from 'lodash'

export interface IState extends IGridProps {
    projects: [],
    selectedProject: [],
    createdByName :string,
    addDialogVisible: boolean,
    blazerId: string,
    username: string,
    selectedRowIndex: number,
    deleteDialogVisible: boolean
}

class Projects extends React.PureComponent<RouteComponentProps<{}>, IState> {
    private baseUrl = properties.baseUrlWs
    private myGrid = React.createRef<JqxGrid>()
    private messages = React.createRef<Messages>()

    private editrow: number = -1;

    constructor(props: RouteComponentProps) {
        super(props);

        this.selectionInfo = this.selectionInfo.bind(this)
       
        this.gridOnSort = this.gridOnSort.bind(this);

        

      const columns: IGridProps['columns'] = [
            { text: 'Project Name', datafield: 'name', width: 390 },
            { text: 'Project Description', datafield: 'description', width: 390 },
            { text: 'Owner Assigned', datafield: 'institutionId', width: 180,hidden:true },
            { text: 'Created By',  datafield: 'createdBy', 
              
                                  
                cellsrenderer: (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties): string => {

                            axios
                            .get("api/personnels/"+value) 
                            .then(response => {
                              
                                    this.setState({
                                        createdByName: response.data.displayedValues 
                                    }, ()=> {
                                        console.log('Inside axios response after setting the state to the name of the project creater')
                                    })
                                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
                            
                
                return this.state.createdByName;

                }
               
            }
           
            ]

        const source:any = {
            dataFields: [
                { name: 'id', type: 'long'},
                { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'description', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'url', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'irbProtocol', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'institutionId', type: 'long' },
                { name: 'projectType', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'priority', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'researchDataSetType', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'statusIndicatorId', type: 'long'},
                { name: 'createdBy', type: 'string' }
            ],
            dataType: 'json',
            root: 'projects',
            sortColumn: 'name',
            sortdirection: 'asc',
            url: this.baseUrl + 'api/projects/search/getProjectsById',
            data: {
                value: ''
            }
        }

        const dataAdapter:any = new jqx.dataAdapter(source,
            {
                autoBind: true,
                downloadComplete: (data:any, status:any, xhr:any):void => {
                    // if (!source.totalrecords) {
                        source.totalrecords = parseInt(data['page'].totalElements);
                    // }
                },
                formatData: (data:any):any => {
                  
                    data.page = data.pagenum
                    data.size = data.pagesize
                    if (data.sortdatafield && data.sortorder) {
                        data.sort = data.sortdatafield + ',' + data.sortorder;
                    }
                    return data;
                },
                loadError (xhr, status, error) {
                    throw new Error('Error occurred in getting Projects for user ' + error.toString());
                }
            }
        );

        

        this.state = {
            projects: [],
            selectedProject: [],
            createdByName : '',
            blazerId: '',
            username: '',
            addDialogVisible: false,
            selectedRowIndex: null,
            deleteDialogVisible: false,
            columns: columns,
            rendergridrows: (params: any): any[] => {
                const data = params.data
                return data;
            },
            source: dataAdapter,
           
        };
    }

    setValueProperty = (data:any):any => {
        if (this.state && this.state.blazerId) {
            data.value = this.state.blazerId
        }
    }

   

    private gridOnSort(event: any): void {
        const sortinformation = event.args.sortinformation;
        let sortdirection = sortinformation.sortdirection.ascending ? 'ascending' : 'descending';
        if (!sortinformation.sortdirection.ascending && !sortinformation.sortdirection.descending) {
            sortdirection = 'null';
        }
        this.myGrid.current.updatebounddata('sort')
    };

    selectionInfo = (event: any): void => {
        const selection = this.myGrid.current.getrowdata(event.args.rowindex)

       this.setState({
            selectedProject: selection
        }, () => {
            console.log('pushing ' + this.state.selectedProject)
            this.props.history.push({
                pathname: '/project',
                state: {
                    project: this.state.selectedProject,
                    blazerId: this.state.blazerId
                }
            })
        });
    }

   

   

   
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('In Projects.componentDidMount....' + sessionStorage.getItem('loggedInUser'))
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('loggedInUser') != null) {
            const loggedInUser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedInUser') as string)
            this.setState({ employeeId: loggedInUser.employeeId})
        }
    }

    render() {
        

        const defaultView = this.state.addDialogVisible ? null : (this.state.employeeId && !_.isEmpty(this.state.employeeId)) ? (
            <div style={{width: '100%', margin: '0 auto', display: 'table'}}>
                <JqxGrid
                    // @ts-ignore
                    ref={this.myGrid}
                    theme={'arctic'}
                    altrows={true}
                    width="100%"
                    autoheight={true}
                    source={this.state.source}
                    columns={this.state.columns}
                    pageable={true}
                    sortable={true}
                    onSort={this.gridOnSort}
                    pagesize={20}
                    virtualmode={true}
                    rendergridrows={this.state.rendergridrows}
                    showtoolbar={true}
                    rendertoolbar={this.state.rendertoolbar}
                    columnsresize={true}/>
            </div>
        ) : null

       

        return (
            <div className="project-page-main">
            <Messages ref={this.messages} style={{width: '100%', margin: 'auto' }}/>
            <div className="content">
               
                {defaultView}
              
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Projects;
```

Comment: I think you have an infinite loop in componentDidMount

Comment: Hmm. Any idea  how can I fix it or if I should try something else?

Comment: if (sessionStorage.getItem('loggedInUser') != null && !this.state.employeeId)  / Instead of your current condition.

Comment: Thanks but it's still happening and I only see this in console log ` console.log('Inside axios response after setting the state to the name of the project creater')` and not the one inside `componentDidMount` so I am assuming it's going in a ninfinite loop inside `cellsrenderer` function only.

Comment: Added few more details in my post related to the error

Comment: Try moving your api call to component did mount

Comment: But how would I get `value` parameter for each record in that case? OR if you could answer my question with your suggestion, that would be great. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the code that wasn't necessary to the explanation.

This is just to give you an idea of how you could move your api call in componentDidMount. There might be some modifications to make since I don't use jQuery with React I might have make false assumptions. In particular, I assumed you could know what values will be fetched in advance.

In you cellrenderer function you will get the value directly from the state:

```
cellsrenderer: (
            row,
            columnfield,
            value,
            defaulthtml,
            columnproperties
        ): string => {
                if(typeof this.state?.createdByName[value] === 'undefined') return ''
                return this.state?.createdByName[value];
        },
```

A getCreatedByName function to call the api.

```
getCreatedByName = async (value: string) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('api/personnels/' + value);
        return { response: response.data.displayedValues, value };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return { response: 'error', value };    
    }
}
```

On componentDidMount you call your api with your values. You wait for all the api call to resolve so that you don't update the state multiple times.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let promises: Promise<{ value: string; response: string }>[] = [];
    const values = [`Value1`, 'Value2'];
    values.forEach((value) => {
        promises.push(this.getCreatedByName(value));
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then((responses) => {
        const createdByName: any = {};

        responses.forEach((response) => {
            createdByName[response.value] = response.response;
        });

        this.setState(
            {
                createdByName,
            },
            () => {
                console.log(
                    'Inside axios response after setting the state to the name of the project creater'
                );
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this error `Cannot find name 'async'.ts(2304)` while defining `getCreatedByName` function.

Comment: I edited the function declaration, tell me if it works now.

Comment: Yeah that error is gone and now seeing following in console `Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable getCreatedByName`

Comment: Where did you put getCreatedByName? It's supposed to be a method of your Projects class.

Comment: I put it just above this line - `const columns: IGridProps['columns'] = [` in my code inside my Project class.

Comment: I think you put it inside your constructor. Put is just above ComponentDidMount()

Comment: Thanks. One Issue I am wondering about is how to get the `const values = [`Value1`, 'Value2'];` in componentDidMount. That basically needs to be coming from the `value` parameter of cellsrender function. Not sure if I would have to make another `api/projects/search/getProjectsById` call inside componentDidMount to retrieve those values or if it is a wrong approach.